# Creating a link in Chrome Extension popup window using __MSG_@@extension_id__ with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension where I have a popup window. When user authentication fails, the **popup window** shows a notification that login was unsuccessful and I wish to include a link to my extension **options page** in that notification. So I am doing this in popup window javascript file:

```
function notifyHTML(html) {
    $("#notification_bar").html(html);
    $("#cont").fadeIn(30).delay(3000).fadeOut(300); //notify    
}
function onLoginFailed() {
    console.log("From extension: Login failed. Check username-password");
    notifyHTML("Login Failed. Update in <a href=\"chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/html/options.html\">Options</a> page");
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<div>
          <div id="cont"><div id="notification_bar"></div></div>
          <!-- More HTML -->
</div>
```

But doing this results in a invalid link in that notification. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code

```
function onLoginFailed() {
    console.log("From extension: Login failed. Check username-password");
    retStr = "Login Failed. Update in <a href=\"chrome-extension://" + chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id") + "/html/options.html\">Options</a> page";
    notifyHTML(retStr);
}
```

You should use **`chrome.i18n.getMessage()`** API to use any predefined message.

## Reference

- [chome.i18n](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n.html)

Answer (score 1):

Better option would be using `chrome.extension.getURL`:

```
function onLoginFailed() {
  console.log("From extension: Login failed. Check username-password");
  notifyHTML('Login Failed. Update in <a href="' + chrome.extension.getURL("/html/options.html") + '">Options</a> page');
}
```

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL